# Why does this "loading message" script not work in FF?(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

I have this script which should show the text "Loading..." while images are loading, then change the text to "loaded" when all images are loaded. I added a button to load new images to make sure that it works for dynamically loaded images as well.

This works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox the "Loading..." text never appears. I have no idea why this would be. The page begins loading and not all images are loaded so it should create the text "Loading.." but it doesn't. Then when all images are done loading the text "Loading" appears.

I just don't get why one message would appear and the other wouldn't. Especially because there are no qualifications that have to be met before creating the "Loading..." text, it should just fire automatically.

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2JrTc/2/) | [Full Page Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2JrTc/2/embedded/result/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var checkComplete = function() {
        if($('img').filter(function() {return $('img').prop('complete');}).length == $('img').length) {
            $('.status').text('Loaded');
        } else {
            $('.status').text('Loading...');
        }
    };

    $('img').on('load',function() {
        checkComplete();
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('img.a').attr('src' , 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8545/8675107979_ee12611e6e_o.jpg');
        $('img.b').attr( 'src' , 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8677371836_651f586c99_o.jpg');
        checkComplete();
    });

    checkComplete();
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that once the images are in your browser cache, you may never see the `Loading...` prompt because they will all load quickly.

Comment: @jfriend00 (first comment) Yes, I am aware of that and have tested it without the images in the cache. I also used very large image files so I can actually see them loading. Before they have loaded it should show the message "Loading..." but it doesn't. I can't figure out why.

Comment: I would go with timer executing `checkComplete()` (optimized version as @jfriend00 second comments is true) every X milliseconds and stopping when all images are loaded. The `.load()` event is just not reliable enough for images.

Comment: @jfriend00 (second comment) Could you explain this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I had considered this, but was trying to get around using a timer. Executing `checkComplete()` only when it is needed seems more appropriate than executing it continuously.

Comment: Just noticed that all of this might be result of a bug. The filter function should be `return $(this).prop('complete');}` in your current code you check only if the first image is complete.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good catch. Thanks for looking through my code. As jfriend said, make it an answer.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon.(?)

I changed it and it still isn't working. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/hcarleton/2JrTc/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues in the code.

First off, the `checkComplete()` function is not written correctly.  It should be this:

```
var checkComplete = function() {
    var imgs = $('img');
    if(imgs.filter(function() {return this.complete;}).length == imgs.length) {
        $('.status').text('Loaded');
    } else {
        $('.status').text('Loading...');
    }
};
```

The main fix here is that the filter callback needs to refer to `this.complete`, not to `$('img').prop('complete')` because you are trying to filter a single item at a time.

Second off, you are relying on both `.complete` and `.load` working correctly AFTER you've changed the `.src` value.  This is explicitly one of the cases where they do not work properly in all browsers.

The bulletproof way to work around this is to create a new image object for the new images, set the onload handler before you set the `.src` value and when both onload handlers have fired, you will know that both new images are loaded and you can replace the once you have in the DOM with the new ones.

Here is a version that works in FF:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var imgA = new Image();
        var imgB = new Image();
        imgA.className = "a";
        imgB.className = "b";
        var loaded = 0;
        imgA.onload = imgB.onload = function() {
            ++loaded;
            if (loaded == 2) {
                $("img.a").replaceWith(imgA);
                $("img.b").replaceWith(imgB);
                $('.status').text('Loaded');
            }
        }
        // the part with adding now to the end of the URL here is just for testing purposes to break the cache
        // remove that part for deployment
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        imgA.src = 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8545/8675107979_ee12611e6e_o.jpg?' + now;
        imgB.src = 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8677371836_651f586c99_o.jpg?' + now;
        $('.status').text('Loading...');
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yy7GX/

---

If you want to preserve the original objects, you can use the newly created objects only for preloading the new images and then change .src after they've been preloaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var imgA = new Image();
        var imgB = new Image();
        var loaded = 0;
        imgA.onload = imgB.onload = function() {
            ++loaded;
            if (loaded == 2) {
                $("img.a")[0].src = imgA.src;
                $("img.b")[0].src = imgB.src;
                $('.status').text('Loaded');
            }
        }
        // the part with adding now to the end of the URL here is just for testing purposes to break the cache
        // remove that part for deployment
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        imgA.src = 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8545/8675107979_ee12611e6e_o.jpg?' + now;
        imgB.src = 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8677371836_651f586c99_o.jpg?' + now;
        $('.status').text('Loading...');
    });
});
```

Working demo of this version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ChSQ5/

Comment: Thanks for the response.

So trying to check all images for the `complete` property in this way is futile and I should just go with the method of checking at set intervals?

Comment: (after Edit)
Alright, I'll try creating new image objects instead of just changing the `src` property. The reason I did it this way was that I wanted to retain all classes set on the current image object, as well as some -data- properties.

Comment: @moss - I added a version of the code and a working jsFiddle to my answer that makes new image elements.  It works in Firefox.

Comment: @moss - you could wait for the images to load on the newly created objects and then set `.src` on your original objects.  That would let you preserve the original properties on the original objects, but use new objects for detecting when loaded.

Comment: @moss - I added a version to my answer that preserves the original objects.

Comment: Nice, I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery API `.load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> #### Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the `.load()` shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: I knew about the browser cache caveat, but was unaware that "It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser".

If this is the case how are you supposed to test if all images have loaded?